# Fast OrderBook Implementation - Follow Up

Tags: c++, homework, c++20, finance

Following up from: [Fast OrderBook Implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285623/fast-orderbook-implementation)

Here is the updated version (I've also implemented some extra functionality)

==> Order.hpp <==

```
struct Order {
    int id;
    int quantity; // hiddenQuantity needs to be >= peakSize
    int peakSize;
    int hiddenQuantity;
    short price; // we don't really need this, cause price is the index

    Order(int id = 0, int quantity = 0, int peakSize = 0, int hiddenQuantity = 0, short price = 0) :
        id(id),
        quantity(quantity),
        peakSize(peakSize),
        hiddenQuantity(hiddenQuantity),
        price(price) { }
};
```

==> OrderBook.cpp <==

```
#include "OrderBook.hpp"

template<Side side>
inline bool OrderBook::compare(const int &top, const int &bottom) {
    if constexpr (side == Side::Bid)
        return top >= bottom;
    else
        return top <= bottom;
}

template<Side side>
inline void OrderBook::findNextPrice() {
    Book &bookSide{books[side]};

    while (compare<side>(bookSide.top, bookSide.bottom) and bookSide.orders[bookSide.top].empty())
        if constexpr (side == Side::Bid)
            --bookSide.top;
        else
            ++bookSide.top;

    if (not compare<side>(bookSide.top, bookSide.bottom))
        bookSide.makeDefault();
}

inline void OrderBook::replenishIcebergOrder(Order &order) {
    if (order.quantity == 0 and order.hiddenQuantity > 0) {
        order.quantity = std::min(order.peakSize, order.hiddenQuantity);
        order.hiddenQuantity -= order.quantity;
    }
}


template<Side side>
void OrderBook::processOrder(Order &order) {
    constexpr Side otherSide = (side == Side::Bid) ? Side::Ask : Side::Bid;
    matchOrders<side, otherSide>(order);
    displayOrderBook();
}

template<Side side, Side otherSide>
void OrderBook::matchOrders(Order &order) {

    auto &otherBook{books[otherSide]};

    while (compare<otherSide>(otherBook.top, order.price) and order.quantity > 0) {
        auto &other = otherBook.orders[otherBook.top].front();

        if constexpr (side == Side::Bid)
            std::cout << order.id << ',' << other.id;
        else
            std::cout << other.id << ',' << order.id;

        std::cout << ',' << otherBook.top << ',' << std::min(other.quantity, order.quantity) << '\n';

        int change = other.quantity - order.quantity;
        other.quantity = std::max(0, change);
        order.quantity = std::max(0, -change);

        replenishIcebergOrder(other);
        replenishIcebergOrder(order);

        if (other.quantity == 0) {
            otherBook.orders[otherBook.top].pop_front();
            if (otherBook.orders[otherBook.top].empty())
                findNextPrice<otherSide>();
        }
    }

    if (order.quantity > 0)
        addOrder<side>(order);
}

template<Side side>
void OrderBook::addOrder(Order &order) {
    Book &bookSide{books[side]};

    if constexpr (side == Side::Bid) {
        bookSide.top = std::max(bookSide.top, static_cast<int>(order.price));
        bookSide.bottom = std::min(bookSide.bottom, static_cast<int>(order.price));
    } else {
        bookSide.top = std::min(bookSide.top, static_cast<int>(order.price));
        bookSide.bottom = std::max(bookSide.bottom, static_cast<int>(order.price));
    }

    bookSide.orders[order.price].push_back(std::move(order));
}

// TODO: is there a better way to do this?
void OrderBook::displayOrderBook() {
    std::cout << "+-----------------------------------------------------------------+\n";
    std::cout << "| BUY                            | SELL                           |\n";
    std::cout << "| Id       | Volume      | Price | Price | Volume      | Id       |\n";
    std::cout << "+----------+-------------+-------+-------+-------------+----------+\n";

    std::vector<std::pair<Order, Order>> orders;
    unsigned long int bidIndex{0}, askIndex{0};

    for (int i = books[Side::Bid].top; i >= books[Side::Bid].bottom; --i) {
        for (auto &order: books[Side::Bid].orders[i]) {
            if (bidIndex >= orders.size()) {
                orders.push_back({order, Order{}});
                ++bidIndex;
            } else {
                orders[bidIndex++].first = order;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = books[Side::Ask].top; i <= books[Side::Ask].bottom; ++i) {
        for (auto &order: books[Side::Ask].orders[i]) {
            if (askIndex >= orders.size()) {
                orders.push_back({Order{}, order});
                ++askIndex;
            } else {
                orders[askIndex++].second = order;
            }
        }
    }

    auto displayField = [](const int &value) {
        return value == 0 ?  "" : std::to_string(value);
    };

    for (const auto &[bidOrder, askOrder]: orders) {
        std::cout << '|' << std::setw(10) << displayField(bidOrder.id) << '|'
            << std::setw(13) << formatWithCommas(bidOrder.quantity) << '|'
            << std::setw(7) << formatWithCommas(bidOrder.price) << '|'
            << std::setw(7) << formatWithCommas(askOrder.price) << '|'
            << std::setw(13) << formatWithCommas(askOrder.quantity) << '|'
            << std::setw(10) << displayField(askOrder.id) << "|\n";
    }

    std::cout << "+-----------------------------------------------------------------+\n";
}

std::string OrderBook::formatWithCommas(const int &value) {
    if (value == 0)
        return "";

    std::string numberString = std::to_string(value);
    for (int i = numberString.size() - 3; i > 0; i -= 3)
        numberString.insert(i, ",");

    return numberString;
}
```

==> OrderBook.hpp <==

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "Order.hpp"

#define BOOK_TOP 32768 // one level above SHRT_MAX
#define BOOK_BOTTOM -1 // one level blow bottom of book
#define BOOK_SIZE 32767 // SHRT_MAX

enum Side { Bid = 0, Ask = 1 };

struct Book {
    /*
    could use a ring buffer/circular queue instead of a deque
    if you know the max possible level depth/width of the orderbook,
    to avoid expensive allocations and deallocations,
    but I decided to keep things simple.
    I chose deque over a doubly linked since it's semi contiguous
    */

    std::vector<std::deque<Order>> orders;

    int top;
    int bottom;
    int defaultTop;
    int defaultBottom;

    Book (long unsigned int size, int top, int bottom) : 
        orders{size},
        top{top},
        bottom{bottom},
        defaultTop(top),
        defaultBottom(bottom) { }

    void makeDefault() {
        top = defaultTop;
        bottom = defaultBottom;
    }
};


class OrderBook {
    
public:

    OrderBook() : 
        books{{Book{BOOK_SIZE, BOOK_BOTTOM, BOOK_TOP}, 
                Book{BOOK_SIZE, BOOK_TOP, BOOK_BOTTOM}}} { }

    ~OrderBook() = default;

    template<Side side>
    inline bool compare(const int &top, const int &bottom);

    template<Side side>
    inline void findNextPrice();

    inline void replenishIcebergOrder(Order &order);

    template<Side side>
    void processOrder(Order &order);

    template<Side side, Side otherSide>
    void matchOrders(Order &order);

    template<Side side>
    void addOrder(Order &order);

    void displayOrderBook();

    std::string formatWithCommas(const int &value);

private:
    std::array<Book, 2> books; // bids, asks
};
```

==> main.cpp <==

```
#include "OrderBook.cpp"

int main() {
    OrderBook orderbook;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        if (line.empty() or line[0] == '#' or line[0] == ' ')
            continue;

        std::istringstream iss{line};
        std::string item;
        std::vector<std::string> items;

        while (getline(iss, item, ','))
            items.push_back(item);

        char side{items[0][0]};
        int id{stoi(items[1])};
        short price{static_cast<short>(std::stoi(items[2]))};
        int quantity{std::stoi(items[3])};
        int peakSize{0};
        int hiddenQuantity{0};

        // error checking
        if ((side != 'B' and side != 'S') or id <= 0 or price <= 0 or quantity <= 0) {
            std::cerr << "Invalid input: " << line << '\n';
            continue;
        }

        // IceBerg order
        if (items.size() == 5) {
            peakSize = stoi(items[4]);
            if (peakSize <= 0 or peakSize > quantity) {
                std::cerr << "Invalid input: " << line << '\n';
                continue;
            }
            hiddenQuantity = quantity - peakSize;
            quantity = peakSize;
        }
        
        Order order{id, quantity, peakSize, hiddenQuantity, price};

        if (side == 'B')
            orderbook.processOrder<Side::Bid>(order);
        else
            orderbook.processOrder<Side::Ask>(order);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example test

```
B,100321,5103,7500
B,100322,5101,7500
B,100323,5103,7500
S,100324,5103,7500
S,100345,5103,100000,10000
  

   # this is a test
# this is another test

# this is going to be invalid
S,1,5103,100,10000

B,2,5103,100
B,3,5103,1000,90
S,4,5103,100,100
S,5,5104,100,100
S,6,5103,100,100


B,7,5105,300,300
S,8,5105,300,100

B,1234567890,32503,1234567890
S,1234567890,32505,1234567890
```

which ofc can be tested by doing something like `cat test | ./order_book`

Comment: By the way, are you targetting C++17 or C++20? It only makes sense to have one of those tags.

Comment: I'm targeting C++20, but for features available in GCC 12

Answer (score 2):

## General Observations

The code is still missing the `#include <sstream>` directive in main.cpp and does not compile for me without it. The file `OrderBook.cpp` is missing the `#include <string>` directive and does not compile without it.

To be honest, I don't see a lot of improvement from the original question.

I still think that the enum `Side` should be a parameter to functions where it is necessary and the templates don't make a lot of sense to me.

I still think that `Side` is not an appropriate name for the enum.

## Include Guards

The header files `Order.hpp` and `OrderBook.hpp` do no contain any form of [include guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020113/c-include-guards), this leads to multiply defined objects in the code and causes linking errors. By adding include guards to the 2 header files I was able to compile and link without problems.

There are 2 forms of include guards you can use in C++, the older style

```
#ifndef ORDER_HPP_
#define ORDER_HPP_

struct Order {
    int id;
    int quantity; // hiddenQuantity needs to be >= peakSize
    int peakSize;
    int hiddenQuantity;
    short price; // we don't really need this, cause price is the index

    Order(int id = 0, int quantity = 0, int peakSize = 0, int hiddenQuantity = 0, short price = 0) :
        id(id),
        quantity(quantity),
        peakSize(peakSize),
        hiddenQuantity(hiddenQuantity),
        price(price) { }
};

#endif // !ORDER_HPP_
```

Or the newer `#pragma once` which is not portable to all compilers.

## C++ Header Files

There are libraries that provide header.hpp files, but the convention is to use header.h rather than header.hpp.

## Constants in C++

There are 3 symbolic constants defined in `OrderBook.hpp`. These 3 symbolic constants are using the older C programming language method of using macros to define constants. In C++ we prefer to use `constexpr` or  `const` assignments because they are type safe where the macros are not type safe.

The existing code is

```
#define BOOK_TOP 32768 // one level above SHRT_MAX
#define BOOK_BOTTOM -1 // one level blow bottom of book
#define BOOK_SIZE 32767 // SHRT_MAX
```

The suggested code is

```
constexpr int BOOK_TOP = 32768;     // one level above SHRT_MAX
constexpr int BOOK_BOTTOM = -1;     // one level blow bottom of book
constexpr int BOOK_SIZE =  32767;   // SHRT_MAX
```

This code should be moved into `OrderBook.cpp`. The constructor for OrderBook should also be moved into `OrderBook.cpp`.

## Use of the `inline` Keyword in Declarations

I mentioned this in the review for the previous version of this question, the keyword `inline` is only a suggestion to the compiler there is no guarantee that the compiler will inline these functions. For better optimization use the compiler optimization switches.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why templating like doesn't make a lot of sense? Is it a matter of style, or is there some reason why this is bad.

Comment: @jpf Not a matter of style. Templates are for generic algorithms, where the code does not depend on a specific type. They are not for replacing arguments/parameters.

Comment: The reason I'm doing it this way is so that I get something similar to template specialisation, is there a better way of doing this without `if constexpr`?

Answer (score 2):

## There's still a hole in `struct Order`

You moved `short price` to the end of the `struct`, but since you also have `int` member variables, the size of the struct will very likely be rounded to a multiple of `sizeof(int)`. You will probably have a `short`-sized hole at the end, which isn't as efficient as making `price` an `int`.

## Missing error checking

In `main()` you are reading input from `std::cin`, but while there is some attempt at validating the input, errors are mostly just ignored. Let's go over the possible errors:

- There might be an error reading a line from `std::cin`. Your `while`-loop will end if that happens, but it treats it the same as if it successfully reached the end of the file. You should check the return value of `std::cin.eof()` after the `while`-loop; if it's not `true`, then something bad happened before reaching the end of the file.
- There might be a problem parsing each line. Splitting the line on commas seems fine. However, `std::stoi()` can sometimes return values even though the string you give it is not purely a number. For example: `"1two3"` will be parsed as `1`. To be more correct, you can use the second parameter of [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to check where it stopped parsing the number; if it's not a NUL-byte, there was some stuff after the number it could not parse.
- Similarly, `items[0]` might be longer than one character, and maybe `items.size() > 5`?
- Even printing to `std::cout` can fail, consider for example someone closing the terminal your program is running in, or if you redirect the output to a file, and the disk is full.

Ideally, you check for all these errors, and if you encounter an error that you cannot deal with *properly*, then you should print an error message to `std::cerr` *and* terminate the program with the [`EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status) exit code.

Just ignoring a line of input you cannot parse is not properly dealing with the issue. It might have been a valid order that was corrupted somehow, or the input might not be a list of orders at all. Ignoring it will result in incorrect or unexpected output.

## Move `enum Side` into a `struct`, `class` or `namespace`

Because `enum Side` is no longer an `enum class`, and you declared it in the global namespace, the names `Bid` and `Ask` are also in the global namespace without needing the `Side::` prefix. It's always better to limit the scope of things. You can move `enum Side` into `struct OrderBook`. Then in `main()` you need to write:

```
if (side == 'B')
    orderbook.processOrder<OrderBook::Bid>(order);
else
    orderbook.processOrder<OrderBook::Ask>(order);
```

Comment: Price has to be a short, sadly nothing I can do about that. I also didn't include much error checking because it's assumed that the input is valid. For the last point, is there a way to use a enum class like how I use it with just enum? I haven't been able to find a way.

Comment: Maybe the price has to be between `SHRT_MIN` and `SHRT_MAX`, but does it matter if you store the value in an `int`? If you assume the input is valid, why still have checks for `side` and `peakSize`? As for `enum class`, you can still use it, but you need to explicitly cast it to an integer: `Book &bookSide{books[static_cast<int>(side)]};` This might be a bit annoying, but you can of course create a helper function for it. Alternatively, put `enum Side` in a `namespace Side`.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to store them as ints, but the spec specifically calls out for a short. if I were to put it in a namespace, wouldn't it also just be better to have have them as bools?

Comment: A `bool` would work, but then you could write `orderbook.ProcessOrder<true>(order)`, which would compile without errors, but what does that mean? It's much better to prevent that and force a symbolic name to be used.

Comment: @jpf Never assume user input will be valid. I learned that a long time ago when I was writing compilers.

Comment: I guess I should have provided more context, this is an assignment, and the markers have told us to assume that the input is valid.